# How to plot multiple y axis values with highchart R?

Tags: r, highcharts

I have data set as example below:

```
emissions<-structure(
  list(
    name = c(
      "China",
      "United States of America",
      "India",
      "Russia",
      "Japan",
      "China",
      "United States of America",
      "India",
      "Russia",
      "Japan",
      "China",
      "United States of America",
      "India",
      "Russia",
      "Japan"
    ),
    iso = c(
      "CHN",
      "USA",
      "IND",
      "RUS",
      "JPN",
      "CHN",
      "USA",
      "IND",
      "RUS",
      "JPN",
      "CHN",
      "USA",
      "IND",
      "RUS",
      "JPN"
    ),
    year = c(
      2019,
      2019,
      2019,
      2019,
      2019,
      2020,
      2020,
      2020,
      2020,
      2020,
      2021,
      2021,
      2021,
      2021,
      2021
    ),
    total = c(100,
              75, 50, 25, 10, 100,
              75, 50, 25, 10, 100,
              75, 50, 25, 10),
    coal = c(100,
              75, 50, 25, 10, 100,
              75, 50, 25, 10, 100,
              75, 50, 25, 10),
    oil = c(100,
              75, 50, 25, 10, 100,
              75, 50, 25, 10, 100,
              75, 50, 25, 10),
    gas = c(100,
              75, 50, 25, 10, 100,
              75, 50, 25, 10, 100,
              75, 50, 25, 10),
    cement = c(100,
              75, 50, 25, 10, 100,
              75, 50, 25, 10, 100,
              75, 50, 25, 10),
    flaring = c(100,
              75, 50, 25, 10, 100,
              75, 50, 25, 10, 100,
              75, 50, 25, 10),
    other = c(100,
              75, 50, 25, 10, 100,
              75, 50, 25, 10, 100,
              75, 50, 25, 10),
    per_capita = c(100,
              75, 50, 25, 10, 100,
              75, 50, 25, 10, 100,
              75, 50, 25, 10)
  ),
  row.names = c(NA,-15L),
  class = c("data.table",
            "data.frame")
)
```

The sample I provided is an example and I have data (emissions) of 230+ countries since 1750. I am trying to plot a line graph that depicts the emissions of each category (coal, oil, gas, cement, flaring, other) for the past 10 years (from 2012 to 2022) with a line graph.

I am unable to figure out how to achieve this. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you specifically have to use highchartR or would alternatives work?

Comment: Anything will work but if it is highchartR I will be more happy!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to create this using highchart:

```
past_10_years<-emissions %>% 
  select(name,year, coal, oil, gas,cement,flaring, other) %>% 
  filter(year>2011) %>% 
  filter(name=="Global")


view(past_10_years)



highchart() %>% 
  hc_xAxis(categories=past_10_years$year) %>% 
  hc_yAxis_multiples(
    list(lineWidth = 3),
    list(showLastLabel = FALSE, opposite = TRUE)
  ) %>% 
  hc_add_series(data = past_10_years$coal, name="Coal") %>% 
  hc_add_series(data = past_10_years$oil, name="Oil") %>% 
  hc_add_series(data = past_10_years$gas, name="Gas") %>% 
  hc_add_series(data = past_10_years$cement, name="Cement") %>%
  hc_add_series(data = past_10_years$flaring, name="Flaring") %>% 
  hc_add_series(data = past_10_years$others, name="Others",type = "spline", yAxis = 1) %>% 
  hc_title(text="Emissions in Past 10 Years",style = list(fontSize = "25px"))
```

Note: Global emissions are present in the data set which became the point of reference.

[image: plot]